# High charts labels display values not names

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a pie chart with highcharts

```
plotOptions: {
          pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                   distance: -30
              },
              showInLegend: true
          }
      },
      series: [{
          name: 'Types',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [ {
              name: 'Debtors',
              y: 10.38
          }, {
              name: 'Suppliers',
              y: 4.77
          },
        ]
      }]
```

Currently in the piechart labels the name of data (that is:Debtors, suppliers) is what is being shown in the pie chart

I would like the values to be displayed instead but the legend should retain the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the format.

```
plotOptions: {
          pie: {
              allowPointSelect: true,
              cursor: 'pointer',
              dataLabels: {
                  enabled: true,
                   distance: -30,
                   format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.y:,.2f}',
              },
              showInLegend: true
          }  
    },
    series: [{
          name: 'Types',
          colorByPoint: true,
          data: [ {
              name: 'Debtors',
              y: 10.38
          }, {
              name: 'Suppliers',
              y: 4.77
          },
        ]
      }]
```

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/powrcnf1/

Comment: @GEOFFREY In case you want to show only values as data labels: http://jsfiddle.net/91uz1jec/.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need an customized tooltip, like this:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () { 
       return this.key + ' (<strong>' + this.y + '</strong>)';
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aabramya/powrcnf1/1/)